# How to display log text exceeding 100,000 lines in fyne?

Tags: go, fyne

What widget should be used to render scrollable log text exceeding 100,000 lines in fyne?

I receive the log text from the socket, and the latest text displays the last line.

The effect is similar to terminal output. I checked the implementation of fyne io/terminal, but it cannot scroll back.

I tried List, but the scrolling didn't seem smooth.

I am looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List is likely the right way, it is capable of that level of content.
If performance is not sufficient then open a bug on the project.